# Given 2 is primitive root (mod p), showing that every non-zero element of Z(p) is expressable as power of [2] (mod p)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

I'm trying to find out how I would go about showing this:

Given a prime number p >= 2, suppose 2 is a primitive root modulo p.
Show that every non-zero element of Z(p) can be written as a power of [2] (mod p).

Z(p) refers to the congruence class modulo p.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't it *the definition* of a primitive root that all the residue classes are its powers? What is your definition of a primitive root?

Comment: Also, please check [our guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) for tips in making your question passable.

Comment: "Isn't it the definition of a primitive root that all the residue classes are its powers?"

Yes, I think so too. Does it matter?

Comment: So there is nothing to prove :-)

Comment: How about I change the word "prove" to "show" or "verify". Does this better describe my question to you?

Comment: @Blackb3ard Since you understand the definition of primitive root, your question is: supposing $2$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, show that $2$ is a primitive root modulo $p$. Are you really stuck there?

Comment: That's not my question. My question is what I wrote in the main-post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch:

In the case $p=2$ the proof is immediate (check), so let $p>2$.

Suppose $2$ is a primitive root mod $p$. By definition, this means that $[2]^{p-1} \equiv 1$ mod $p$ and this is the smallest power of $2$ for which this happens.

Claim: $2^a$ with $a=1,\dots, p-1$ are $p-1$ distinct numbers mod $p$.

Proof: suppose not. Then...

Finally, if the numbers $2^a$ are all distinct mod $p$, then what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it needs "proof" so much as a good "argument".

$2$ being a primitive root means that $2^{p-1} \equiv 1\pmod p$ but for all $k; 1\le k < p-1$ we do not have $2^{k}\equiv 1 \pmod p$.

The $2^k;1\le k \le p-1$ are distinct $\mod p$.

(Why?  Because if $1\le a \le b \le p-1$ are such that $2^a \equiv 2^b \pmod p$ then $2^{a+(p-1)-b} \equiv 2^{b+(p-1)-b} = 2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. As $2$ is a primitive root this is impossible if $a+(p-1)-b < p-1$.  So $a+(p-1) -b = p-1$ and $a = b$.)

And obviously no $2^k \equiv 0 \pmod p$.  (Because $p\not\mid 2^k$).

(Oh... unless $p = 2$.  But $2$ can not be a primitive root $\mod 2$.  $2^k \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ is impossible.)

So the $2^k; 1\le k \le p-1$ are $p-1$ distinct non-zero residue classes....  as are the $p-1$ non-zero elements of $\mathbb Z_p$.  So each non-zero element of $\mathbb Z_p$ is equivalent to one power of $2$ (and vice versa).

That's all.